# JSP nd MySQL classnot found exception

Tags: mysql, jsp, classnotfoundexception, connectivity

I have developed a code in `JSP` and using `Apache Tomcat 8.0` server to run it
and this is my class path to connect with the MySQL server\

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL-connector-java-3.0.17-GA\MySQL-connector-java-3.0.17-GA\MySQL-connector-java-3.0.17-GA-bin.jar;.;`

But still am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`
Can some one please help me to overcome this error?

Comment: The JAR file with JDBC driver has to be in the webapp's classpath, i.e. in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, or in the servlet container's (app server's) `lib` folder.

Comment: Thank You for your answer.But i already fixed it